# Jersey REST api filtering and ordering correctly

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have Jersey REST API and I would like to add ordering by column, filtering by column, base, offset and others. But I cant find concrete answer how it should be, or if is there some best practise to follow. It is header param or query param? And should it by under one param like Order = "name:asc" or two like order_by = "name" and order_order_how = "asc". Or it is completely on me how I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this information is place in query parameters. There are a few patterns I'll see. Both the one that seems the most intuitive to me is as follows

- `/resource?sort=-firstname[,+lastname]`

  The `[]` denotes optionally more criteria. The `+` and `-` denote the order

The reason I like the above pattern rather than something like

- `/resource?sort=firstname&order=asc`

is that with the above pattern, with the separation of the `sort` and `order`, it makes it difficult to ensure correctness with multiple criteria. It seems our algorithm for parsing may be error prone and dependent on the client making careful request.